# Access variables in struct from void pointer

Tags: c++11, struct, casting, void-pointers, data-members

I was wondering if there is a way to access a data member within a `struct` that is being pointed to by a `void*`?  What I'm trying to explain will hopefully be more apparent in my example code:

```
int main()
{
  struct S
  {
    int val;
  };
  S s;
  s.val = 5;

  void* p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(S));
  *(struct S*) p = s;
  std::cout<< *(struct S*)p.val << std::endl;

}
```

I have ran this exact code casting `p` as `*(int*)p` and it printed fine, however, using exact code above results in a compilation error.  Haven't been able to find an example that quite accomplishes this task.  Is it possible to access the data members of the `struct` after it is casted? why or why not? if so, how?

Comment: `std::cout<< (*(struct S*)p).val` or `((struct S*)p)->val` . You just need an extra pair of parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than a C-style cast.  So `*(struct S*)p.val` is treated as `*((struct S*)(p.val))`, which doesn't make sense since `p` is a pointer and does not have members.

So you need parentheses to specify what you intended:

```
std::cout<< (*(struct S*)p).val << std::endl;
```

Or equivalently,

```
std::cout<< static_cast<S*>(p)->val << std::endl;
```

---

[But also: the statement `*(struct S*) p = s;` technically has undefined behavior, even though all most implementations will allow it.  This is because C++ has rules about when an object is created, and there was no object of type `S` previously at that address, and assignment does not create an object except for some cases involving union members. A similar statement that does not have this problem would be `new(p) S{s};`.

Also also: use of `malloc` or `void*` is usually not a good idea in C++ in the first place.  `malloc` should only be used when interfacing with a C library that requires it.  Anything for which `void*` seems useful can probably be done more safely using templates.  In a few cases a `void*` might be the only way to do something or "cleverly" avoid code duplication or something, but still use it sparingly and always with extreme caution.]

Comment: Thanks for your response! It was extremely insightful and straightforward.  I am skeptical about using `void*` as well.  My situation is that I have child classes that essentially get a structure from a base class.  Problem is that I don't know which type of  `struct` will be provided until run time.  So `void*` was my way of trying to "capture" the `struct` no matter the type.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Possibly an interface plus template implementation sort of thing, or maybe a `std::variant` (or `boost::variant` if C++17 is not available).  But it's hard to say without more details. Maybe you could open another question about that.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Performance is a huge consideration and pretty critical.  I have looked into `boost::variant` but have been unable to find timing complexities. I will try to dive deeper into it.